# loop cut in multiple objects blender

Tags: modeling, loop

I want to apply loop cut to all columns, how do I do it at once instead of having to do it one by one?
[image]

Comment: Loop cut doesn't support it. You can select all the vertical edges with for example wireframe view and border selection tool, then use "Subdivide" on them.

Comment: @FFeller I would write this as a proper answer since this is the easiest way to do it and it would even work if the object were not symmetrical (to be mirrored for example).

Answer (score 1):

Since the object and task is relatively simple you can just apply a mirror modifier to both of the pillars and set the main house (the large cube) as the mirror object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).